# ACTION_UP Event in dispatchTouchEvent is Getting Triggered Late

Tags: android, touch, latency, dispatch, touch-event

I make a swipe gesture and track it from dispatchTouchEvent in a ScrollView. However, end of the swipe gesture is being detected one frame later. See the last two events below, last two gestures are ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP. But their touch points are exactly the same, however their eventTimes are different.

action=ACTION_MOVE, x[0]=734.165, y[0]=1241.4056, historySize=2, eventTime=136103401
action=ACTION_**MOVE**, x[0]=**747.8897**, y[0]=**1077.508**, historySize=2, eventTime=**136103418**
action=ACTION_**UP**, x[0]=**747.8897**, y[0]=**1077.508**, historySize=0, eventTime=**136103432**

136103432 - 136103418 = 14. So ACTION_UP is being retrieved 14 ms later. This is preventing some smooth effects I do right after finger leaves the screen.

You can check the full log from here: https://zerobin.net/?a71539bf3862abdb#xXjCPrjk/Fi7l+N++9oivQkieFRQ3KA6gwQ0pU2NTYc=

So, how can I detect ACTION_UP earlier in dispatchTouchEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in Android P. Looks like Google decided to make some real UI animation improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect ACTION_UP until it happens.  The user could leave their finger on the screen for several seconds so you may want to rethink your design

Comment: ACTION_UP is already happening. It is being detected 14 ms later after I leave my finger. There is almost one frame latency. I actually left my finger at last ACTION_MOVE event at 136103418 ms.